# linux guarantee or reserve memory for a specific process

Tags: linux, memory, virtuozzo

Is there a way to reserve a specific amount of memory for a specific service/process?

I would like to guarantee that OpenSSH always has enough memory available to it that it can accept a new SSH connection in case the server's memory fills up.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, don't worry. If memory fills up the OOM killer will "deal" with it for you...at which point you have *two* problems.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1026708/is-there-a-way-to-reserve-some-ram-for-a-process-to-prevent-it-from-becoming-unr

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you don't "reserve" memory on *nix systems - you ensure that there is enough physical RAM + Swap space to handle what your server is doing, and you let the VM subsystem handle it from there (though as dmckee pointed out in Linux you have the "helpful" OOM killer which will kill the "biggest memory user" when you run out of RAM -- the logic of the aforementioned "helpful" subsystem is suspect at best).

You should try to figure out why your system is running out of memory (if that's actually the problem): If you fix the underlying problem you won't need to reserve RAM.

Comment: This problem has happened several times, and it has never been freed up. We had to restart the VPS everytime it happened as we could not SSH in.

I am trying to figure out what is causing it right now. I started this post earlier:
http://serverfault.com/questions/110918/linux-log-memory-hogging-issue

Comment: @helphost: Generally the OOM killer does it's job very reliably. If the system is getting exceedingly slow but not stopped, then you have too much swap in place and the thrashing is taking circa 100% of the available CPU. If it is just freezing in may not be memory related at all.

Comment: That bias taken into account however, @dmckee is on the money - the OOM killer will make sure you have free memory (You just might not like what is kills to get you to that point :-)

Comment: This is actually a Virtuozzo VPS. So there is 0 swap available. Is it possible that the OOM killer isn't running for us because as far as it can see, the server is not out of memory, only our allocated memory in our VPS?

Comment: @helphost: **Ah...** That is another situation entirely...good question. You might want to edit question text to reflect it, though.

Comment: @helphost: I'm not too familiar with how Virtuozzo works, but from quick googling it sounds like it's the source of your problem -- The "containers" aren't really virtual servers (so no local OOM killer within the VM, and if the host isn't out of memory its OOM killer won't kick in)